# Conditional formatting highlighting extra rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Having issues with conditional formatting highlighting additional columns and rows.If R=0 then the row should not be highlighted. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Se6Cxk8-QqxvR7kWbch1GDH1nS-Su76B_e-Qk3wVtb4/edit?usp=sharing

Here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your:

```
=$R2=0
```

into:

```
=$R5=0
```

---

## UPDATE:

[image: 0]